# Cannot show UICollectionView with Segmented Control

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

In my main view Controller, I have a segmented control and a container view below. I want to change the container view whenever I switch the segmented control. When I switch over the tab, I can see the very view being loaded (print in viewDidload), however, I find it not working with the datasource of collectionViewDataSource. Any ideas?

[image]

```
// Main View
let videoViewController = VideoViewController()
let photoViewController = PhotoViewController()


private var activeViewController: UIViewController? {
    didSet {
        removeInactiveViewController(oldValue)
        updateActiveViewController()
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    activeViewController = videoViewController

}

@IBAction func segmentDidChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        print("\(sender.titleForSegmentAtIndex(0)!) Selected")
        activeViewController = videoViewController

    } else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        print("\(sender.titleForSegmentAtIndex(1)!) Selected")
        activeViewController = photoViewController
    }
}


private func removeInactiveViewController(inactiveViewController: UIViewController?) {
    if let inActiveVC = inactiveViewController {
        // call before removing child view controller's view from hierarchy
        inActiveVC.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)

        inActiveVC.view.removeFromSuperview()

        // call after removing child view controller's view from hierarchy
        inActiveVC.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
}

private func updateActiveViewController() {
    if let activeVC = activeViewController {
        // call before adding child view controller's view as subview
        addChildViewController(activeVC)

        activeVC.view.frame = containerView.bounds
        containerView.addSubview(activeVC.view)

        // call before adding child view controller's view as subview
        activeVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
}
```

```
// PhotoView
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    print("HI")
}
extension PhotoViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as!PhotoCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    // Configure the cell
    cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "test")
    return cell
}
}
```

When I make the PhotoViewController as initial controller, it works.

[image]

Comment: I think `collectionView` is not being loaded upon addsubview as a view.

Comment: try `activeVC.collectionView.reloadData()` in `updateActiveViewController` method before adding its view to subview of container.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the UIContainerView and UISegmentControl, if you use ContainerView show single UIViewController are already posted and the link are given below,

[When I add a UIContainerView to a view controller it's type is UIView. How do I get to the viewcontroller for the embedded view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368866/when-i-add-a-uicontainerview-to-a-view-controller-its-type-is-uiview-how-do-i/36369526#36369526)

or If you use ContainerView show two UIViewController when alernatively click UISegmentControl, to show single viewcontroller code is given below,

[image: First create main ViewController, with create segmentController and containerView, then create Two ViewController name 'FirstViewController' and 'SecondViewController', then you put CollectionView from Any ViewController.]

If you create the storyboard, then go MainViewController Class and create the outlet are

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentControl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIViewController *currentViewController;
```

ViewDidLoad method:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                           forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
    [segmentControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    _currentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
    _currentViewController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
    _currentViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self addChildViewController:_currentViewController];
    [self addSubview:_currentViewController.view toView:_containerView];
```

And UISegmentController method is given below,

```
-(IBAction)indexChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        UIViewController *newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
        newViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self cycleFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:newViewController];
        self.currentViewController = newViewController;
    }
    else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        UIViewController *newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
        newViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self cycleFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:newViewController];
        self.currentViewController = newViewController;
    }
}
```

And the two view related Methods are,

```
- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)subView toView:(UIView*)parentView {
    [parentView addSubview:subView];

    NSDictionary * views = @{@"subView" : subView,};
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[subView]|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:0
                                                                     views:views];
    [parentView addConstraints:constraints];
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[subView]|"
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:0
                                                            views:views];
    [parentView addConstraints:constraints];
}

- (void)cycleFromViewController:(UIViewController*) oldViewController
               toViewController:(UIViewController*) newViewController {
    [oldViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:newViewController];
    [self addSubview:newViewController.view toView:self.containerView];
    [newViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];

    // set starting state of the transition
    newViewController.view.alpha = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         newViewController.view.alpha = 1;
                         oldViewController.view.alpha = 0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [oldViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                         [oldViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                         [newViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                     }];
}
```

if you use these code alternativelly open the ViewController from UIContainerView when click SegmentControl, if work CollectionView from FirstViewController and its working for me!

Hope its helpful..

Comment: I'm able to switch over two views in the container with segmented controller, however, I got an error message if the view I added is collectionviewController.

Comment: Error Msg occurs in addsubView: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'

Comment: if switch over two views in container with segmented control while using uitableview its working fine for me, i think you collectionview some error, its layout problem and i have solution given below  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288927/uicollectionview-must-be-initialized-with-a-non-nil-layout-parameter)